# Connect devices to networks that require a browser based user/pass

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I'm starting university in a few days, and I've got a Sonos and PS4 that I don't think support a browser based user/pass system when connecting to the internet. There will be an Ethernet port in my room, but I'm assuming this still requires a browser based user/pass.

My university is using a system called `eduroam`.

Is there a way I can connect these devices to the network? Is there an authentication device I can plug in via Ethernet, and any devices connected to it automatically get authenticated?

Comment: You'd have to setup a devices that does the authentication for you. Probably some kind of proxy server on e.g. your computer and your devices would connect to your computer in order to access the internet. As it is a campus maybe ask around what other students did, you're probably no the only one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plug in a router (if you're allowed) then get past the captive portal (browser based user/pass) on the router by using a laptop connected to the router.  Then see if the connection is shared successfully by other devices on the router.

This may work if the university is white-listing MAC addresses, because the only MAC address they would see would be the MAC of the router.   Unfortunately, most colleges and universities have rules against using your own router.

Answer (score 0):

Captive portal services generally have a site where you can manually enrol MAC addresses. For the specific university network in question, it's https://hallnet.info/cgi-bin/Roombase4/macmanage. If you're unsure of this address, ask your network administrator.

1. Open the above URL on a device which has already completed enrolment.
2. Log in with your existing credentials.
3. Enter the MAC address of the device you wish to connect.
4. Wait a few minutes, then reconnect the device you added to the network.

Comment: Sup George, this worked for the PS4. The Sonos couldn't be discovered as being able to see other devices on the network is disabled. I had to buy a router, plug it into the ethernet port in my room, then setup the Sonos to this router. This solution can be used for printers too.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I’ve rolled back your edit, the link is not dead. The TLD is .local, i.e. DNS resolved by the local network, and hallnet.info is resolved by eduroam’s DNS, the *edu*cation *roam*ing network in Europe mentioned in the question.

Comment: @grg Ahhh… Got it. Perhaps you should clarify that in the answer itself since the link is active for all but not reachable unless one is on that network itself.